# Changing the Value of a label from a list.

Tags: list, javafx, binding

I am trying to make a guessing game where the program will display a sequence of a number one at a time. I have the sequence randomly generated from a list but I have not been able to display the values in the list one at a time. I want to change the label using bind but I can't seem to make it work.

```
public class Tutorial extends Application {

    Stage window; 
    Scene scene1, scene2; 
    Label label; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage; 

        //Scene 1
        Label welcome = new Label("Welcome to the Guessing Game. Press Start to Enter");
        Button start =  new Button("Start"); 
        VBox firstlayout = new VBox(10); 
        firstlayout.getChildren().addAll(welcome, start); 
        firstlayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        start.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

        scene1 = new Scene(firstlayout, 450, 300); 
        window.setScene(scene1);


            ArrayList<Integer> guessList = numbergen(); 




         Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(getValues(guessList)));


            label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-padding: 10px; -fx-font-size: 50px");

            FadeTransition fader = createFader(label);

            SequentialTransition Fader = new SequentialTransition(
                    label,
                    fader
            );


            StackPane layout = new StackPane(); 
            layout.getChildren().addAll(label); 


           scene2 = new Scene(layout, 250, 300); 

            Fader.play();



    window.setTitle("Program Close");
    window.setScene(scene1);

    window.show(); 

    }

private FadeTransition createFader(Node node) {
    FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(5), node);
    fade.setFromValue(1);
    fade.setToValue(0);

    return fade;
}

     public ArrayList<Integer> numbergen(){ 
            ArrayList<Integer> numb = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            Random rand = new Random();

            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

            int n = rand.nextInt(5) + 1; 
                numb.add(n); 
            }   
            return numb; 
        }

        public boolean result(ArrayList<Integer> solnList, ArrayList<Integer> guessList){ 

            if(solnList.size() != guessList.size()){ 
                return false; 
            }else{ 
                for(int i = 0; i<solnList.size(); i++){ 
                    if(solnList.get(i) != guessList.get(i)){ 
                        return false; 
                    }
                }
                return true; 
            }



        }

        public int getValues(ArrayList<Integer> list){ 
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){ 

                return list.get(i); 
            }
            return 0; 
        }





}
```

Comment: Why even generate a sequence list up front here? Why not just generate a new random number whenever you need one and use that?

Comment: How would I generate a random number whenever I need it? I'm fairly new at Java so this is confusing me a lot.

Comment: The same way you are currently generating random numbers.  Call `rand.nextInt(5) + 1`, but only do it when you need it.  I don't know when that is, you would have to determine it.  My advice, as you are new to Java, is not to start with trying to write a UI or to use binding.  Learn java first and only start trying to create UIs after you are proficient in basic java.  For your number guessing game, write the core engine and objects in plain java with junit test code to verify it.  When the engine is working add a command line console based interface to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a binding to an integer list element, you can use:

[`Bindings.integerValueAt(observableList, observableIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#integerValueAt-javafx.collections.ObservableList-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-)

For example:

```
label.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.integerValueAt(observableList, observableIndex).asString()
);
```

where observableIndex in an IntegerProperty which refers to the current index of an element in the list whose value you wish to be bound to.

When you call `observableIndex.add(1)`, then the binding value will change appropriately.

Comment: Where would I be implementing this at?

Comment: You can just stick the bind in your start method as it never changes.  The observable index change would probably happen on some user interaction, e.g. after the user guesses the last correct number, then index is incremented so that user can guess the next number.

Comment: I did it. I made a loop and used

label.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.integerValueAt(observableList, observableIndex).asString()
);

But now it only give me the last value.

Comment: A loop isn't the way to do this.  You want to change the index on user interaction, not in a loop.